# Working with \lstlistoflistings in the apa6 documentclass

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, apa-style, apa6

I would like to insert a List of Listings including the section number in my Table of Contents. [The listings documentation](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) is not sufficient to solve this problem.

**I am using the apa6 documentclass, which is by default unnumbered.** I already introduced some tweaks to introduce numbering into the toc. In particular, I hacked around a similar problem with the List of Figures by doing:

```
\section{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{}
\listoffigures
```

Please see the two images below to see what the problem is. A minimum working example (MWE) is added below.

The List of Listings is missing here:

[image: The List of Listings is missing here!]

The List of Listings should be numbered, but isn't:

[image: The List of Listings should be numbered!]

This is the Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[doc,11pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\titlevariable}{Good Paper}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Snippet}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}

% Turning section numbering back on (turned off by apa6 document class)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{datetime}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{\titlevariable}

\author{A Cool Guy}
\affiliation{Nice Uni}
\shorttitle{\titlevariable}

\abstract{\ \\
    Abstract ABC
}
\keywords{A, B, C}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} \maketitle 

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\newpage 

\thispagestyle{empty} \tableofcontents 

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Foo Section}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
Some Fancy Code
\end{lstlisting}

\newpage \printbibliography

\section{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{}
\listoffigures

\newpage  %\section{List of Code Snippets}
% \renewcommand\lstlistingname{}
%\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\begingroup\tocfile{\lstlistingname}{List of Code Snippets}\endgroup}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Code Snippets}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {}ANEXOS:}{}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{8\ \ List of Code Snippets}
%\addtocounter{section}{1}
\lstlistoflistings

\newpage \section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing things is really a bit hacky, and it would be preferable to use the regular sectioning commands for the Lists. To do this, I've used the `tocloft` package, with the `[titles]` option, which will use the standard sectioning commands. Since it uses `\section*` instead of section, I've patched the commands using `etoolbox` to get rid of the `*` in the relevant `\listof...` commands.

The `listings` code works a little differently, so for that list, I've simply redefined its command to match the standard `\listof...` definitions.

`biblatex` defines the bibliography heading code differently again, but it has built-in methods to redefine it. This must be done at the beginning of the document, so I've wrapped the relevant command in `\AtBeginDocument`.

I've removed irrelevant packages and code from your example document, but moved `hyperref` to the end of the preamble as a reminder: it should generally be loaded last.

```
\documentclass[doc,11pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{datetime}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
% redefine bibheading to be a regular section
\AtBeginDocument{\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
\section{#1}%
\markboth{#1}{#1}}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Snippet}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Code Snippets}
% Use standard sectioning code for lstlistoflistings
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\section{\lstlistlistingname }\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \lstlistlistingname }{\MakeUppercase \lstlistlistingname }\@starttoc {lol}}
\makeatother
% Make listoftables and listoffigures numbered sections
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{*}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{*}{}{}{}


% Turning section numbering back on (turned off by apa6 document class)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{datetime}


\usepackage{hyperref} % load this as late a possible

% Separate content assignment from package loading
\newcommand{\titlevariable}{Good Paper}
\title{\titlevariable}

\author{A Cool Guy}
\affiliation{Nice Uni}
\shorttitle{\titlevariable}

\abstract{\ \\
    Abstract ABC
}
\keywords{A, B, C}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} \maketitle 

\thispagestyle{empty} 



\thispagestyle{empty} 
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Foo Section}

\textcite{aksin}


\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
Some Fancy Code
\end{lstlisting}




\section{This is the appendix}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you for the clean solution and for the helpful comments in the code! I'm learning a lot from this. Highly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question? I now have the same problem with the bibliography (Biblatex with Biber backend). It prints "References" without a number, not in bold, and "References" does not appear in the toc. How can I make the \printbibliography command behave like the other lists? \patchcmd{\printbibliography}{*}{}{}{} does not work here.

Comment: @JanSpörer I've updated the answer to show how to change the the bibliography heading in `biblatex`. The patching commands depend very specifically on how the command you are patching is defined, so you can't generalize them over arbitrary commands.

Comment: Works, I just had to change \bibname to \refname in your answer. Thanks again!!